# Deprecated php $HTTP_POST_FILES

Tags: php

I'm trying to correct deprecated PHP code, in this case `$HTTP_POST_FILES` but I am unsure if I still need to declare `global` i.e change `global $HTTP_POST_FILES` to `global $_FILES` I'm guessing not. Would the following re-code be correct?

Original code snippet:

```
function upload_doc($fieldName)
{
global $HTTP_POST_FILES;
if (isset($HTTP_POST_FILES[$fieldName]) &&
.......more stuff
```

Re-code:

```
function upload_doc($fieldName)
{
if (isset($_FILES[$fieldName]) &&
.......more stuff
```

Comment: `$_FILES` is already in the global scope so you should not have to make it global.

Comment: Trying to rewrite old code, so hopefully at least this one is correct. Thanks for your help.